Genetic Algorithm - car trajectory
I'm trying to implement Genetic Algorithm to get from point A to point B by car in python. So it's more like a proof of concept.
import sys
import math
import random

POPULATION_SIZE=10
GENE_LENGTH=10 
MUTATION_RATE=.1
ELITISM=.1
ELITISM_IDX=int (ELITISM*POPULATION_SIZE)
GENERATIONS=20
MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE=18
FRICTION=.85
WIDTH=16000
HEIGHT=9000
MIN_FITNESS=0
MAX_FITNESS=100000

def distance(ax, ay, bx, by):
    return math.sqrt(pow(ax-bx,2)+pow(ay-by,2))

def validate_angle(cur_angle,desired_angle):
    angle_diff=(desired_angle-cur_angle+360)%360
    if angle_diff>180:
        angle_diff-=360
    angle_change=max(-MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE,min(angle_diff,MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE))
    new_angle=(cur_angle+angle_change)%360
    return int(new_angle)

def validate_position(x,y,vx,vy,angle,thrust):
    rad_angle=math.radians(angle)
    vx+=int(math.cos(rad_angle)*thrust)
    vy+=int(math.sin(rad_angle)*thrust)
    x+=vx; y+=vy
    vx=int(vx*FRICTION); vy=int(vy*FRICTION)
    return x,y,vx,vy

def generate_individual():
    chromosome=[]
    x,y,vx,vy,angle=init_x,init_y,init_vx,init_vy,init_angle
    for _ in range(GENE_LENGTH):
        desired_angle=angle+random.uniform(-MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE,MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE)
        angle=validate_angle(angle,desired_angle)
        thrust=random.randint(0,200)
        x,y,vx,vy=validate_position(x,y,vx,vy,angle,thrust)
        chromosome.append((int(angle),int(thrust)))
    return chromosome

def generate_population():
    return [generate_individual() for _ in range(POPULATION_SIZE)]

def simulate(chromosome):
    x,y,vx,vy,angle=init_x,init_y,init_vx,init_vy,init_angle
    for gene in chromosome:
        desired_angle,thrust=gene

        angle=validate_angle(angle,desired_angle)
        x,y,vx,vy=validate_position(x,y,vx,vy,angle,thrust)

        if distance(x,y,*checkpoint)<=600:
            solved=True

    return x,y,vx,vy,angle

def fitness(chromosome):
    global solved
    x,y,vx,vy,angle=simulate(chromosome)
    if y>HEIGHT or y<0 or x>WIDTH or x<0:
        return MIN_FITNESS
    if solved:
        print("Solution found !",file=sys.stderr)
        return MAX_FITNESS
    else:
        fitness=-distance(x,y,*checkpoint)
        return fitness
    
def selection(population):
    population.sort(key=lambda chromosome: fitness(chromosome), reverse=True)
    return population[:ELITISM_IDX],population[ELITISM_IDX:]

def crossover(parent1, parent2, counter):
    child=[]
    for i in range(GENE_LENGTH):
        crossover_point=random.random()
        angleP1=parent1[i][0]; angleP2=parent2[i][0]
        thrustP1=parent1[i][1]; thrustP2=parent2[i][1]

        angle=crossover_point*angleP1+(1-crossover_point)*angleP2
        thrust=crossover_point*thrustP1+(1-crossover_point)*thrustP2
        if not counter%2:
            angle=(1-crossover_point)*angleP1+crossover_point*angleP2
            thrust=(1-crossover_point)*thrustP1+crossover_point*thrustP2
        if i==0:
            angle=validate_angle(init_angle,angle)
        else:
            angle=validate_angle(child[-1][0],angle)
        child.append((int(angle),int(thrust)))
    return child

def mutate(chromosome):
    for i in range(GENE_LENGTH):
        mutate_point=random.random()
        if mutate_point < MUTATION_RATE:
            angle=validate_angle(chromosome[i][0],chromosome[i][0]+random.uniform(-MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE,MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE))
            thrust=random.randint(0,200)
            chromosome[i]=(int(angle),int(thrust))
    return chromosome

def roulette_wheel_selection(probabilities):
    cumulative_probabilities=[sum(probabilities[:i+1]) for i in range(len(probabilities))]
    r=random.random()
    for i,cumulative_probability in enumerate(cumulative_probabilities):
        if r<cumulative_probability:
            return i

def is_valid_chromosome(chromosome):
    for gene in chromosome:
        if gene[1]>HEIGHT or gene[1]<0 or gene[0]>WIDTH or gene[0]<0:
            return False
    return True

def calc_fitness_probabilities(population):
    fitnesses=[fitness(chromosome) for chromosome in population]; 
    min_fitness=min(fitnesses)
    normalized_fitnesses=[fitness-min_fitness+1 for fitness in fitnesses]; 
    total_fitness=sum(normalized_fitnesses)
    fitness_probabilities=[fitness/total_fitness for fitness in normalized_fitnesses]
    return fitness_probabilities

def print_population(population):
    for chromosome in population: 
        print(chromosome,file=sys.stderr)
        print(f"Fitness {fitness(chromosome)}",file=sys.stderr)
        print("",file=sys.stderr)
    print("",file=sys.stderr)

solved=False
init_y=init_x=init_vy=init_vx=init_angle=0
checkpoint=(2757, 4659)
prev=0
init_x, init_y, init_vx, init_vy, init_angle = 10353, 1986, 0, 0, 161
population=generate_population(); #print_population(population)
generation=1

while not solved:
    print(f"Generation {generation}",file=sys.stderr)
    elites_population,commons_population=selection(population)

    fitness_probabilities=calc_fitness_probabilities(commons_population); 
    counter=1
    while len(elites_population)<POPULATION_SIZE:
        parent1=roulette_wheel_selection(fitness_probabilities); 
        while not is_valid_chromosome(commons_population[parent1]): parent1=roulette_wheel_selection(fitness_probabilities)
        parent2=parent1
        while parent1!=parent2 and not is_valid_chromosome(commons_population[parent2]): parent2=roulette_wheel_selection(fitness_probabilities)
        child=crossover(commons_population[parent1],commons_population[parent2],counter)
        child=mutate(child)
        if child not in elites_population:
            elites_population.append(child)
            counter+=1
    population=elites_population
    population.sort(key=lambda chromosome: fitness(chromosome), reverse=True)
    print_population(population)
    best_chromosome=max(population,key=fitness)
    best_fitness=fitness(best_chromosome)
    print(f"\nBest fitness: {best_fitness}\n",file=sys.stderr)
    generation+=1
    

I'm trying to find the correct set of genes for that. Gene consists of 2 values: thrust and angle.
Unfortunately I either get stuck with the same genes, even though I filter out same pairs. Or my car get's out of the map.
I'm sure I'm missing something basic here, it's just I can't pinpoint what exactly.

Some remarks: (1) Bug: while parent1!=parent2 and not is_valid_chromosome(commons_population[parent2]) should probably be while parent1==parent2 or not is_valid_chromosome(commons_population[parent2]). The original while-loop is never executed. (2) Crossovers only happen in the common_population, the elite doesn't mate. (3) You use validate_angle for restricting the angle in the physical simulation as well as for crossover and mutation. Maybe it should only be used in the physical simulation.

Yes, you were absolutely right ! I've removed angle validation inside crossover as well as map validation inside fitness and it finds a solution in first generation (as it should). Thanks !

I fail to grasp why anyone who wants actual solutions would use this approach. Cars cannot drive in arbitrary directions, they follow a network of roads (unless they are going cross-country, in which case they follow a network of paths connecting passages through geographic barriers). Something like Dijkstra’s algorithm would seem like a far more sensible approach to me.

@pjs as I have noted in the initial description it's nothing more then a proof of concept, besides it's just a simplified problem from point A to point B ;)

So just 2 modifications and it finds a solution:
def fitness(chromosome):
    x,y,vx,vy,angle=simulate(chromosome)
    #This has to go
    """if y>HEIGHT or y<0 or x>WIDTH or x<0:
        #print("Out of map !",file=sys.stderr)
        return MIN_FITNESS"""
    if solved:
        print(f"{x} {y}",file=sys.stderr)
        return MAX_FITNESS
    else:
        fitness=-distance(x,y,*checkpoint)
   return fitness


def crossover(parent1, parent2, counter):
    child=[]
    for i in range(GENE_LENGTH):
        crossover_point=random.random()
        angleP1=parent1[i][0]; angleP2=parent2[i][0]
        thrustP1=parent1[i][1]; thrustP2=parent2[i][1]

        angle=crossover_point*angleP1+(1-crossover_point)*angleP2
        thrust=crossover_point*thrustP1+(1-crossover_point)*thrustP2
        if not counter%2:
            angle=(1-crossover_point)*angleP1+crossover_point*angleP2
            thrust=(1-crossover_point)*thrustP1+crossover_point*thrustP2
        #This has to go too
        """if i==0:
            angle=validate_angle(init_angle,angle)
        else:
            angle=validate_angle(child[-1][0],angle)"""
        child.append((int(angle),int(thrust)))
 return child

This is a working solution !

I'm not 100% sure what you want. But if you just want to limit the range of the "car" and get different genes, you can just do selective generation instead of full regeneration; you can also provide more rules to close off the car range. Try this:
import sys
import math
import random

POPULATION_SIZE = 10
GENE_LENGTH = 10
MUTATION_RATE = 0.1
ELITISM = 0.1
ELITISM_IDX = int(ELITISM * POPULATION_SIZE)
GENERATIONS = 20
MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE = 18
FRICTION = 0.85
WIDTH = 16000
HEIGHT = 9000
MIN_FITNESS = 0
MAX_FITNESS = 100000

def distance(ax, ay, bx, by):
    return math.sqrt((ax - bx) ** 2 + (ay - by) ** 2)

def validate_angle(cur_angle, desired_angle):
    angle_diff = (desired_angle - cur_angle + 360) % 360
    if angle_diff > 180:
        angle_diff -= 360
    angle_change = max(-MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE, min(angle_diff, MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE))
    new_angle = (cur_angle + angle_change) % 360
    return int(new_angle)

def validate_position(x, y, vx, vy, angle, thrust):
    rad_angle = math.radians(angle)
    vx += int(math.cos(rad_angle) * thrust)
    vy += int(math.sin(rad_angle) * thrust)
    x += vx
    y += vy
    vx = int(vx * FRICTION)
    vy = int(vy * FRICTION)
    return x, y, vx, vy

def generate_individual():
    chromosome = []
    x, y, vx, vy, angle = init_x, init_y, init_vx, init_vy, init_angle
    for _ in range(GENE_LENGTH):
        desired_angle = angle + random.uniform(-MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE, MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE)
        angle = validate_angle(angle, desired_angle)
        thrust = random.randint(0, 200)
        x, y, vx, vy = validate_position(x, y, vx, vy, angle, thrust)
        chromosome.append((int(angle), int(thrust)))
    return chromosome

def generate_population():
    return [generate_individual() for _ in range(POPULATION_SIZE)]

def simulate(chromosome):
    x, y, vx, vy, angle = init_x, init_y, init_vx, init_vy, init_angle
    for gene in chromosome:
        desired_angle, thrust = gene
        angle = validate_angle(angle, desired_angle)
        x, y, vx, vy = validate_position(x, y, vx, vy, angle, thrust)
        if distance(x, y, *checkpoint) <= 600:
            return x, y, vx, vy, angle, True
    return x, y, vx, vy, angle, False

def fitness(chromosome):
    x, y, vx, vy, angle, solved = simulate(chromosome)
    if y > HEIGHT or y < 0 or x > WIDTH or x < 0:
        return MIN_FITNESS
    if solved:
        print("Solution found!", file=sys.stderr)
        return MAX_FITNESS
    else:
        return -distance(x, y, *checkpoint)

def selection(population):
    population.sort(key=lambda chromo: fitness(chromo), reverse=True)
    return population[:ELITISM_IDX], population[ELITISM_IDX:]

def crossover(parent1, parent2, counter):
    child = []
    for i in range(GENE_LENGTH):
        crossover_point = random.random()
        angleP1, thrustP1 = parent1[i]
        angleP2, thrustP2 = parent2[i]

        angle = crossover_point * angleP1 + (1 - crossover_point) * angleP2
        thrust = crossover_point * thrustP1 + (1 - crossover_point) * thrustP2

        if not counter % 2:
            angle = (1 - crossover_point) * angleP1 + crossover_point * angleP2
            thrust = (1 - crossover_point) * thrustP1 + crossover_point * thrustP2

        if i == 0:
            angle = validate_angle(init_angle, angle)
        else:
            angle = validate_angle(child[-1][0], angle)

        child.append((int(angle), int(thrust)))
    return child

def mutate(chromosome):
    for i in range(GENE_LENGTH):
        mutate_point = random.random()
        if mutate_point < MUTATION_RATE:
            angle = validate_angle(chromosome[i][0], chromosome[i][0] + random.uniform(-MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE, MAX_ANGLE_CHANGE))
            thrust = random.randint(0, 200)
            chromosome[i] = (int(angle), int(thrust))
    return chromosome

def roulette_wheel_selection(probabilities):
    cumulative_probabilities = [sum(probabilities[:i + 1]) for i in range(len(probabilities))]
    r = random.random()
    for i, cumulative_probability in enumerate(cumulative_probabilities):
        if r < cumulative_probability:
            return i

def is_valid_chromosome(chromosome):
    for gene in chromosome:
        if gene[1] > HEIGHT or gene[1] < 0 or gene[0] > WIDTH or gene[0] < 0:
            return False
    return True

def calc_fitness_probabilities(population):
    fitnesses = [fitness(chromo) for chromo in population]
    min_fitness = min(fitnesses)
    normalized_fitnesses = [fit - min_fitness + 1 for fit in fitnesses]
    total_fitness = sum(normalized_fitnesses)
    fitness_probabilities = [fit / total_fitness for fit in normalized_fitnesses]
    return fitness_probabilities

def print_population(population):
    for chromo in population:
        print(chromo, file=sys.stderr)
        print(f"Fitness {fitness(chromo)}", file=sys.stderr)
        print("", file=sys.stderr)
    print("", file=sys.stderr)

solved = False
init_y = init_x = init_vy = init_vx = init_angle = 0
checkpoint = (2757, 4659)
init_x, init_y, init_vx, init_vy, init_angle = 10353, 1986, 0, 0, 161

population = generate_population()
generation = 1

while not solved and generation <= GENERATIONS:
    print(f"Generation {generation}", file=sys.stderr)
    
    elites_population, commons_population = selection(population)
    fitness_probabilities = calc_fitness_probabilities(commons_population)
    
    counter = 1
    while len(elites_population) < POPULATION_SIZE:
        parent1 = roulette_wheel_selection(fitness_probabilities)
        while not is_valid_chromosome(commons_population[parent1]):
            parent1 = roulette_wheel_selection(fitness_probabilities)
        
        parent2 = parent1
        while parent1 == parent2 or not is_valid_chromosome(commons_population[parent2]):
            parent2 = roulette_wheel_selection(fitness_probabilities)
        
        child = crossover(commons_population[parent1], commons_population[parent2], counter)
        child = mutate(child)
        if child not in elites_population:
            elites_population.append(child)
            counter += 1
    
    population = elites_population
    population.sort(key=lambda chromo: fitness(chromo), reverse=True)
    
    print_population(population)
    
    best_chromosome = max(population, key=fitness)
    best_fitness = fitness(best_chromosome)
    print(f"\nBest fitness: {best_fitness}\n", file=sys.stderr)
    
    generation += 1

Also, your code might be easier to debug if you used more comments and limited it to the "problem" areas.

Thanks @Peabody jr. ! It was a bit deeper, the issue. But Michael Butscher nipped it in the bud. :)
